# How to access ASPNETDB in C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-membership

I think this is obvious, but it's not coming to me.....forgive me.

Anyway, I am setting up a "Reset Password" component for a web application I am building.  The user will provide his email address. The app will check to see if the email address exists in the database. If the email address exists, send the reset request to an admin to review. Else, prompt the user to create an account (as email addresses are set to be unique per account).

I am having trouble conceiving how to see if the email address exists in the database. I've thought about using LINQ to query the email address in the database if it equals the email address provided by the user.  I've also thought about getting all existing users via Membership, getting each user's email, then making a comparison from there.

FYI, I am doing such logic within the Controller.

How do I access the database (which is [stock] aspnetdb.mdf)?
Am I better off doing this using LINQ, Membership, or another way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with in regards to accessing the database?

Comment: Don't access the Db directly, use the provider.

Comment: @Oded Within the code (I can access it through Data Connections fine). For example, I would like to call 'db.table' to retrieve info.

Comment: @Henk How do I go about that?

Comment: @edmastermind29 - I still don't get it. Please post a code example of what you want to do.

Comment: @Oded [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720472/trying-to-access-the-aspnetdb-mdf-database-file-to-get-user-information-asp-ne) demonstrates how to get users. I would like to be able to get user's emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go through the provider interface:

```
 string userName = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(emailToCheck);
 if (userName != null)
     ...
```

Comment: I knew it was obvious (DUH). Thanks, Henk.